# Error: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am trying to get some user status information (isDeleted: true/false) form a Firebase Realtime DB when a user wants to login to the mobile app. While trying this, I got this error:

> Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

The code looks like this:

**login.page.ts**

```
  loginUser() {
    const data = this.loginForm.value;
    if (!data.userName) {
      return;
    }

    this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Loading...'
    }).then((res) => {
      res.present();
    });

    const credentials = {
      email: data.userName + this.username_domain,
      password: data.password
    };

    this.authService.loginUser(credentials)
      .then(res => {
        this.userService.setOrgId(res.user.photoURL);
        this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs');

        //The error occours here.
        this.userService.getUserStatus().then((isDeleted: any) => {
          console.log('isDeleted ', isDeleted)
          if (isDeleted) {
            err => {
              this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
              this.toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                message: 'Your account is not active anymore.',
                duration: 2000
                  });
              } 
              this.authService.logoutUser()
              .then(async (res) => {
                this.clearLocalData();
                this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('login');
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }
        });

      }, err => {
        this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
        this.toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: err.message,
          duration: 2000
        }).then((toastData) => {
          toastData.present();
        });
      });
    }
```

**user.service.ts**

```
getUserStatus() {
   firebase.database().ref(`organizationData/${this.orgId}/users/${this.uId}/isDeleted/`).get().then(function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      }
      else {
        console.log("No data available");
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUserStatus()` doesn't return anything, you have to do the following:

```
getUserStatus() : Promise<DataSnapshot> {
   return firebase.database().ref(`organizationData/${this.orgId}/users/${this.uId}/isDeleted/`).get();
  }
```

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thanks a lot Peter.

Comment: But now im not getting the flag into the login.page.ts function. Do you might also have a solution for that?

Comment: are you getting this `isDeleted`?

Comment: I am getting user.service.ts:51: "true" but login.page.ts:84: "undefined". Sorry, but I am quite new to TS.

Comment: did you change the service function as i said? Try and use `.then((snapshot: DataSnapshot) => {`

Comment: I changed it to this:  'getUserStatus() : Promise<any> {
    return firebase.database().ref(`organizationData/${this.orgId}/users/${this.uId}/isDeleted/`).get().then(function (snapshot) {'

Comment: otherwise I would get: Cannot find name 'DataSnapshot'.ts(2304)